# What is the output of the following C code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    for(;y;printf("%d%d\n",x,y))
        y = x++ <= 5;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused about the structure of the for construct in the code snippet above. It's taken form a book on programming in C.

The correct output is the following according to the book.

```
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 0
```

Can someone explain how and why this is the output?

Comment: Tip:http://ideone.com/

Comment: execute it and see for yourself.

Comment: Hint: Print the value of x and y as long as y is true..

Comment: There are many [online compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) available if you don't have a compiler available. Most of them support C.

Comment: @karthikr: While `y` is true, rather?

Comment: @karthikr or until false

Comment: To all downvoters : read the question. The title might be poorly chosen, but the question in the description is legitimate.

Comment: @franssu: Why miss an [opportunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shitstorm)? Reading is overrated.

Comment: @franssu, the question itself is as bad as the title. if he wants help understanding `for`, `+=`, `printf`, or any other feature, he can ask (or better, read a book). But he asks "why is this the output"?

Answer (score 2):

To understand what the `for` loop does, here is the equivalent `while` loop:

```
while (y) {
    y = x++ <= 5;
    printf("%d%d\n",x,y);
}
```

The transformation goes like this:

```
for (INIT; COND; INC) {
  BODY;
}
```

->

```
INIT;
while (COND) {
  BODY;
  INC;
}
```

Note that in C the expression `y` is equivalent to `y != 0` if `y` is an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The construct becomes easy to understand if you expand it.
I reckon the trick here is in understanding that the suffix incrementation of x happens after the comparison.

Another concept shown in your example is the fact that in C all comparisons return a boolean value (1 for true and 0 for false).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 1;

    printf("first version:\n");
    for(;y;printf("%d%d\n",x,y))
        y = x++ <= 5;
    printf("second version:\n");
    x = 1;
    y = 1;

    while (y != 0)
     {
        if (x <= 5)
          y = 1;
        else
          y = 0;
        x = x + 1;
        printf ("%d%d\n",x,y);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: _Also, the for construct is equivalent to a do ... while and the loop is always executed at least once._
**Wrong.** Please explain me what happens if the condition fails on the first iteration. Say, in the above code `int x = 1, y = 0;`

Comment: you're right, my bad. I'm editing the post. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize how for loop works in C:

```
for(initialization; condition; expression) {
     //statements
}
```

1. **initialization** is executed before the first evaluation of the **condition**
2. **expression** is evaluated after every iteration of the loop.
 3. The loop will only be entered when the **condition** is true.

In your code, please note that in the line,

```
y = x++ <= 5;
```

' x ' is compared with the number 5 before its value is incremented. For example, on the 5th iteration x=5 is checked against (<=5), then it is incremented to 6. After that the statement

```
printf("%d%d\n",x,y)
```

is executed printing "61".